# How does a class/instance object actually access methods from the memory's Text/Method Segment in Java/Objective C?

Tags: java, objective-c, object, memory

As far as I understand (please correct me if I'm wrong), methods from classes are stored in the Code/Text Segment of the memory in C/Objective C. In Java, methods are stored in the Method Area (equivalent to Code/Test Segment). Methods could be allocated at compiled-time. I also believe that each object, whether class or instance, is not instantiated with the method codes every single time. Instead, methods are created once in the Code/Text Segment. Then the object instances, which are located in the Heap Segment, have to somehow access/relate to these methods.

1) Do the objects store the memory address of the methods in their data?

2) What about inheritance, do the objects somehow (through the keywords such as "extends") also store the memory address of their superclass' methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Question 1 and Question 2 tried to give me a direction toward the original one which was: How does a class/instance object actually access methods from the memory's Text/Method Segment in Java/Objective C?

Unfortunately, both questions were actually heading the wrong direction. Here is what I now know:

a) Objects are simply a blocks of variables (properties) which are grouped together. If broken down into pieces, objects are simply a collections of primitive variables, which are grouped together in a particular manner (hence, array-style or custom class-style). They do not, by any chance, carry any information about their methods. This is true for most class-based languages such as Java, Objective-C or Swift. However, prototype-based language like Javascript, things are quite different.

b) Methods are actually a separate entity from objects. Methods, like functions, reside in the Code Area and are simply blocks of binary instructions. Whenever you call a method, you actually access that blocks of binary instruction through a pointer-like memory address of the method. This memory address is exposed through the function/method identifier (name). All methods are just like functions, most of them are actually sharing the same scope as global functions. Each function/method names are unique (to the compiler) and represent a very specific memory address.

Therefore, when you call a method by invoking its name, the program can access that specific location as represented by the function identifier. Hence, functions are created once in the Code Area. Unlike regular function, a method must require an instance of a specific class in order to work. That's basically the whole point of method - a specialized function which requires a specific set of data coming from an object to perform a specialized task. Therefore, whenever a method is use, an object instance is required to accompany it. The compiler simply help you to automatically pass in the pointer of the object as parameter to methods of a specific class, and store it in local variables such as "self" or "this". In other words, the only link between object and its methods is that the compiler automatically create an object pointer as a hidden parameter for a method; and require you to instantiate an existing object to fulfill that hidden parameter and allow the methods to be invokable.

Answer (score 0):

Normally code of a program is stored in the Code Segment which is also called Text Segment. 
***For more information on different segments:***

http://www.beingdeveloper.com/memory-layout-of-a-program/

Basically Code Segment has a field called "**Offset**", which is the offset address at which the instructions are available.

As an example, suppose the program (binary) loads at memory location 0x802...

And the Code Segment would have entries like this:

```
Offset       Info                 Type   Sym.Value  Sym. Name
0000002d  00000501 R_386_32 00000000   .rodata
00000032  00000a02 R_386_PC32      00000000   printf
00000044  00000501 R_386_32 00000000   .rodata
00000049  00000a02 R_386_PC32      00000000   printf
```

The actual memory location at which the code is loaded is : **Offset + program (binary) load location**.

***Detailed Explanation:***

http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it did not actually answer my questions. I have posted the answer. Thanks again :)